# ECR passport issue

Tags: visas, uae

My old passport, in which ECR was stamped, expires in 2022. I have a Dubai work visa on this passport , but as I was told that it'd be a problem for me to travel to Dubai, I got a new passport with ECNR with a new passport number.

So will it be a problem for me to travel or do I have to transfer my UAE work visa to my new passport?